# How to update the man in bash

Tags: linux

I have been trying Linux recently so my questions must be too much easy for you .Anyway

I try to look the man of lseek but there is no man for this function . I'd like to know how to update the man of linux on bash.

thank in advance

Comment: Do you wish to update a manpage or the man program?

Comment: What distribution are you running? Typically you can install additional man-pages through your package manager.

Answer (score 10):

On Debian the commands would be (as root)

```
apt-get install man-db
apt-get install manpages-dev
```

And for completeness

```
apt-get install glibc-doc
```

Comment: Please click "accept" then :-)

Comment: Once installed, how do you edit the man pages and contribute them upstream?